# Collision detection between UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uikit, collision-detection

I'm playing around with UIKit dynamics, I have two UIImageViews with an UICollisionBehavior, it's delegate is fired when the two views collide, the problem is, if the image is a circle the frame is a square and even the frames are colliding that's not what I really want.

How the collision is detected:

[image]

How I want to be detected:

[image]

Is there a workaround to achieve this?. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** The images aren't circles, so I'll probably have to use UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsTypePath and transform my UIImage to a UIBezierPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a subclass of UIImageView and implement:

```
override var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .Ellipse
    }
```

or

```
-(UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType) collisionBoundsType {
    return UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsTypeEllipse;
}
```

For more information see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/206/#)

Comment: Question updated. Thanks to your anwer I found the UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsTypePath, now I just have to play a little since tutorials are not that common. Thank you